# How can I display multiple pandas series histograms in the same jupyter notebook cell?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, histogram

I have a dataset with an obvious stratification and I'm looking for graphical evidence that there is a difference in their histograms. Suppose for here that my data set looks something like

```
id | cat | hour
---------------
1  | a   | 14
5  | c   | 9
```

If I try and plot each of the histograms for a fixed categorical variable, then I get overlapping graphs. For example, if I write

```
unique_cats = list(df["cat"].unique())
for cat in unique_cats:
    df[df["cat"] == cat]["hour"].hist(bins=24, rwidth=0.9,
                                      normed=True, alpha=0.3)
```

then I get a bunch of overlapping histograms. Here's a screenshot:

[image: overlapping histograms]

How can I have my histograms have their own separate line in my jupyter notebook?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Sorry, I did not intend on keeping that :) But, I added a screenshot showing the problem

Comment: By "their own separate line" you mean you want to have one figure or subplot per histogram?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want!

Comment: Figures and subplots are not the same thing. Which one would you prefer?

Comment: @DavidG You're right, in my case though from what I can understand the difference really doesn't matter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to create a new figure (`plt.figure()`) for each category:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({"cat": np.random.choice(list("ABC"), size=100),
                  "hour" : np.random.rand(100)})
unique_cats = list(df["cat"].unique())
for cat in unique_cats:
    plt.figure()
    df[df["cat"] == cat]["hour"].hist(bins=24, rwidth=0.9,
                                      normed=True, alpha=0.3)
```

[image]